# APPCRASH while running Explorer

Tags: windows

I keep getting the following error:

Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Explorer.EXE
  Application Version:  6.1.7601.17514
  Application Timestamp:    4ce7a144
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_423a
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18247
  Fault Module Timestamp:   521eaf24
  Exception Code:   c0000374
  Exception Offset: 00000000000c4102
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    7177

Anyone know what the hell is going on?

Additional Information 1: 423a
  Additional Information 2: 423adab2099b2868015cb9460891eb88
  Additional Information 3: 4f89
  Additional Information 4: 4f898d4b07fd532255598c947d770589

Comment: wacky context menus from third-party shell extensions - try disabling one by one would be my first guess

Comment: I wouldn't know what to disable. The only third party stuff I have added are McAfee and blue tooth headphones software!

Comment: I get the same crash, on Outlook. But what's StackHash_423a!? There's no module like that in the file system!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured this problem too on my windows 7 ultimate i.e. sometimes my explorer or games won't respond and finally they crash. This can be solved using simple steps or common fixes below.

**These are some simple starter troubleshooting steps you can perform. Try them out which might help you.**

**1**. The first thing you should do is to backup your docs, music, videos, etc. to a particular drive, make a new user profile in windows and restore your backup.

**2**. A bad or corrupt Context Menu may be the reason for crash of explorer. You can troubleshoot using **TPS** (Third Party Software) known as "shell extension viewers". ShellExView is one of them. The rule is to disable non-Microsoft context menu handlers *one-by-one* and verify if the problem is solved. If disabling one does not solve the problem, undo the disabled item and disable the next non-Microsoft handler. Do the same until the problem is solved and finally identify the culprit. Scroll right to see the Company Name column in ShellExView. You can download it in the link below:

**Link: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html**

**3**. Sometimes tweaking or fixing of registry may help to handle app crashes. You can download TPSs to fix registry (errors) like Iobit reg. fix or GlarySoft Registry Fix. "GlarySoft Registry Repair" is a free registry repair tool. You can download it in the link below:

**Link: http://www.glarysoft.com/registry-repair/**

**4**. "sfc /scannow" which stands for system file checker scans the integrity of all protected Windows 7 system files and replaces incorrect corrupted, changed, or damaged versions with the correct versions if possible. Type it command-prompt.

You can start commmand-prompt by **win+R**, type **cmd**.
Type **sfc /scannow**, press enter.

I hope above steps helps you.
AT

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be attending to this, this evening and will let you know if I am successful.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is tearing his hair out over this for days and days like I did:

I had the same problem  -  when authenticating at a SMB share, regardless of the Server (Windows/Linux) on the other side, the Explorer would crash with this message. I tried pretty much exactly what Abhigyan proposed in his answer to no avail.

The solution for me: Deinstalling the "**CSR Harmony Wireless Software Stack**"  -  this (obviously faulty) Bluetooth driver/stack (installed version was **2.1.63.0**) was the cause; deinstalling it solved the problem on two of my Windows 7 installations.